# Raspberry pi Thermal printer python Twitter query with hashtags

Tags: python, twitter, raspberry-pi, thermal-printer

my problem is, using the adafruit python scripts for the raspberry pi, interfacing with a thermal printer they sell, they have a twitter api extension that can do twitter queries. i am trying to do a hashtag query, but python code sees the hashtag and makes the rest of the line commented out.

the python string looks like this

`queryString = '#THN'`
where the hashtag should not be commented out.

i am using nano from the command line and it changes the text color from green to red, so i know it is seeing it as commented out code. 
hopefully this makes sense.

link to adafruit raspberry pi thermal printer tutorial: https://learn.adafruit.com/pi-thermal-printer/

and link to twitters api search help page:
https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: What happens if you try to run the code? I think nano is just displaying the text in red mistakenly (it's seeing the `#` but not that you've wrapped in it quotes.  Python should run the code correctly.

Comment: yeah that looks like thats whats happening. i thought it wasnt working because of what nano was displaying but that wasnt the case at all.